# Show that J is a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be the ring of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the operations
$$(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$
$$(fg)(x) = f(x)g(x)$$
Let $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$. Show that $J = \{f ∈ R | f(c) = 0\}$ is a maximal
ideal.
Can you give me some hints ?

Comment: Look at the quotient map from $R$ to $R/J$, it should have a nice interpretation in terms of what it does to some function $f \in R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\in R$ such that $f(c)\neq 0$. All you have to prove is that the ideal $\langle J, f \rangle=R$. However, this is straightforward. Let $g\in R$, then we can write

$$ g=\frac{g(c)}{f(c)} f + \underbrace{\left(g - \frac{g(c)}{f(c)} f\right)}_{\in J}.$$

Hence, $g\in \langle f, J \rangle.$ As $g\in R$ was arbitrary we get $R=\langle f, J\rangle$ and hence $J$ is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 4):

We know $J$ is maximal if and only if $R/J$ is a field. Consider the map $e:R\to \mathbb{R}$ given by evaluation at $c$. What is the kernel? Apply the first isomorphism theorem and you should be in business.

Comment: I think you mean $e: R \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Of course; thanks for the catch!